# Django Login App Returning 403 Forbidden, CSRF Issues

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I'm using this [tutorial](http://solutoire.com/2009/02/26/django-series-1-a-custom-login-page/) to try out creating a django login application (super simple stuff...)

This is the code I end up with in my template (`index.html`)

```
<div id="login-box">
            {{ state }}
            <form class="login-widgets" action="/login/" method="post">
                {% if next %}
                <input class="login-widgets-text" type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                {% endif %}
                Username :
                <input class="login-widgets-text" type="text" name="username" value="{{ username}}" /><br />
                Password :
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
                <input class="login-button" type="submit" value="Log In" />
            </form>
            <!--<div class="login-widgets">
                <p>Username : ___________</p>
                <p>Password : ___________</p>
            </div>-->
      </div>
```

And this is what the tutorial told me to add to my app `views.py` page:

```
def login_user(request):
    state = "Please log in below..."
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."

    return render_to_response('index.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})
```

I set up my test database exactly as it was described in the tutorial and on the django docs, but still my login keeps getting this error in the browser:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

I don't understand what it means by CSRF verification - in my `settings.py` I have set up the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES with the following:

> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
>       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>       'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>       # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
>       # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', )

But I'm not sure how to verify the CSRF and authenticate login. As far as I know, the database super user and the code above looks correct, except I don't know how to add CSRF verification. 
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `{% csrf_token %}`inside your form. It will be replaced by a hidden input with a key.

Step by step [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it).

Concept [explanation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works).

Comment: Any where in the form?

Comment: It gave me the following error: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py:58: UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  warnings.warn("A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.")`

Comment: @gersande It's commonly written right after opening it: `<form  ... >{% csrf_token %}`.

Comment: The error went away when I put the csrf token right after opening the form. Unfortunately the browser is still giving me an error: `Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

Comment: Follow [this steps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it).

Comment: You're probably missing one of the middlewares or context processors.

Comment: Also, check that you have a `SECRET_KEY` in `settings.py`. It's generated by django when you do `django-admin.py startapp` You might have deleted it by mistake.

Comment: I still have a my SECRET_KEY and as far as I know, I was really careful to use all the right middlewares...

Comment: and the template context processors? You need `django.core.context_processors.csrf`, otherwise you'd have to include the csrf manually in each of your views.

Comment: Okay when I added that bit of code to the top of `settings.py`, the app refuses to compile and gives me this error in the terminal: `ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`

Comment: This did not really solve my problem, but I'm going to move away from this tutorial and start from scratch based on the docs you've given me. Thanks very very much.